# When can you trust first-order QED?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, perturbation-theory, approximations

In QED, we use the perturbation expansion. Usually, we use the first-order perturbation expansion, and sometimes the second. I want to know, physically, what conditions need to be satisfied for us to have good reason to believe that the first term or two of the perturbation expansion is a good approximation to the true answer?

I'm broadly aware that if we have sufficiently strong external background fields then that makes the higher-order terms important. I'm more interested in the case where we don't have background fields. Then, I think that higher-order corrections seem to come bundled with powers of $p^2/m^2$, where $p$ is the momentum moving through the interaction?

So, I suppose I have two questions:

1. Are there any quantitative results that make this a little more precise? Do we have a rule of thumb for precisely how much energy we need our particles to carry before the first term or two of the perturbation expansion aren't "good enough"? 2 times the electron rest energy? 100 times?
2. Is the energy of the constituent particles being low enough the only condition?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your "tolerance". On one hand, a first-order **elastic scattering cross section** (i.e., in the first Born approximation) is finite and "well" describes the experimental data. But later on you learn that purely elastic processes do not happen because there always emission of soft photons with a unity probability, and it is an **inclusive cross section** who is finite.

There is an interesting analogy with scattering from atoms (see my [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2635) publication on this subject).

Comment: Presumably "uninty probability" is a typo.

Comment: Interesting! Do you think that the fit of first-order theory to experiment is dependent on the electron being within a certain energy range? (Ignoring that at *really* high energies you'd need non-QED standard model.) Or is that specific quantity always well-predicted by first-order QED, and it's just other quantities (such as the emitted soft photons) that it can't describe?